# Prevent Duplicate Email Adresses Entry to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm wanting to prevent duplicate entries. If the Email Address already exists, I want to display a message saying something like "Email Address already exists within the database"

Here is my Create Method within my CustomerController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName,FirstName,EnrollmentDate,Email")] Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }

    return View(customer);
}
```

How would I go about adding a check to see if the email address already exists in the database?

Comment: Consider using a `RemoteAttribute` to give you client side validation [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). But if you want just server side validation, you need to query the database to check if there is a match and then add a `ModelStateError` if there is

Answer (score 4):

You can check to see if a customer exists with a given email before saving.

```
var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailAddress == Email);

if (customer == null)
{
  // save changes
}
```

Or handle this in the database via a unique constraint. You can then catch and handle the exception.

```
USE TestDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE Users
 (
   UserID int NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1), 
   Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   Surname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   EmailAddress varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT AK_UnqueEmail UNIQUE(EmailAddress) 
); 
GO
```

If you are applying the Unique constraint to an existing table you would structure your code as below:

```
 USE TestDB; 
GO
ALTER TABLE Users 
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_UniqueEmail UNIQUE (EmailAddress); 
GO
```

REF: https://lgitsmart.com/2014/10/18/sql-server-tip-preventing-duplicate-records-using-the-unique-constraint/

Comment: Regardless of which method you choose, you should always have the constraint in the database to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

you could update your model so you don't need to check if it is already used

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Customer
{
    ..... {get; set;}
    ..... {get; set;}
    //String Length = 450 will avoid error if string is set to max
    [StringLength(450)]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string Email{get;set;}
}
```

or you could add this in your mapping (if you are using fluent)

```
  public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
  {
    public CustomerMap()
    {
      // ....
      Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(450).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new[] { new IndexAttribute("Index") { IsUnique = true } }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I agree I was stuck with EF Core for the same, its a pity that there're no Data Annotations available yet. Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/unique-constraints